# CodeIgniter inserting data into db

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I'm start working with PHP, and I am totally noob with PHP, and while I inserting data into table, nothing happened. 
I try to change my model and controller, I checked everything but I can not see where I made mistake

**Post controller**

```
<?php


class Posts extends CI_Controller{

    function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->database();
        $this->load->model('Posts_model');
    }

    public function index($page='home'){


        $data['posts']= $this->Posts_model->get_posts();

        $this->load->view('templates/header');
        $this->load->view('posts/index',$data);
        $this->load->view('templates/footer');
    }


    public function view($mjestoOdredista=NULL){
        $data['posts'] = $this->Posts_model->get_posts($mjestoOdredista);

        if(empty($data['posts'])){
            show_404();
        }
        $data['id'] =$data['posts'];

        $this->load->view('templates/header');
        $this->load->view('posts/view',$data);
        $this->load->view('templates/footer');
    }


    public function create(){
        $data['title'] ='Create Posts';

        $this->form_validation->set_rules('mjestoPolaska','Mjesto Polaska', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('mjestoOdredista','Mjesto Odredista', 'required');

        if($this->form_validation->run()===FALSE){

            $this->load->view('templates/header');
            $this->load->view('posts/create',$data);
            $this->load->view('templates/footer');

        }else {
            $this->Posts_model->create_post();
            redirect('posts');
        }

    }

    public function delete($id){

        $this->Posts_model->delete_post($id);
        redirect('posts');
    }

    public function edit($mjestoOdredista){
        $data['mjestoOdredista']= $this->Posts_model->get_posts($mjestoOdredista);

        if(empty($data['mjestoOdredista'])){
            show_404();
        }
        $data['id'] = 'Edit Post';

        $this->load->view('templates/header');
        $this->load->view('posts/edit',$data);
        $this->load->view('templates/footer');
    }


    public function update(){

        $this->Posts_model->update_post();
        redirect('posts');

    }

    }
```

**Posts Model**

```
<?php
 class Posts_Model extends CI_Model{

    public function __construct(){
        $this->load->database();
    }

     function get_posts($mjestoOdredista=FALSE){
        if($mjestoOdredista === FALSE){
            $this->db->order_by('id','DESC');
            $query=$this->db->get('posts');
            return $query->result_array();  
        }
        $query=$this->db->get_where('posts', array('mjestoOdredista' => $mjestoOdredista));
        return $query->row_array();
    }

    //Kreiranje post
    public function create_post(){

        $mjestoPolaska = url_title($this->input->post('title'));

        $data=array(
                'mjestoPolaska' => $mjestoPolaska,
                'mjestoOdredista' => $this->input ->post('mjestoOdredista'),
                'vrsta_usluge' => $this->input ->post('vrsta_usluge'),
                'datum_polaska' => $this->input ->post('datum_polaska'),
                'datum_povratka' => $this->input ->post('datum_povratka'),
                'cijena' => $this->input ->post('cijena'),
                'broj_mjesta' => $this->input ->post('broj_mjesta'),
                'opis' => $this->input ->post('opis'),

        );

        return $this->db->insert('posts',$data);


    }

    public function delete_post($id){
        $this->db->where('id',$id);
        $this->db->delete('posts');
        return true;
    }

    public function update_post(){
        $mjestoPolaska=url_title($this->input->post('Mjesto Polaska'));
        $data=array(
                'id' =>$this->input->post('id'),
                'Mjesto Polaska' => $this->input ->post('mjestoPolaska'),
                'Mjesto Odredista' => $this->input ->post('mjestoOdredista'),
                'Vrsta usluge' => $this->input ->post('vrsta_usluge'),
                'Datum Polaska' => $this->input ->post('datum_polaska'),
                'Datum Povratka' => $this->input ->post('datum_povratka'),
                'Cijena' => $this->input ->post('cijena'),
                'Broj Mjesta' => $this->input ->post('broj_mjesta'),
                'Opis' => $this->input ->post('opis'),

        );
        $this->db->where('id',$this->input->post('id'));
        return $this->db->update('posts',$data);

    }

    }



 ?>
```

**Create view**

```
<h2><?= $title;?></h2>
<?php echo form_open('posts/create');?>
<?php echo validation_errors();?>

<!DOCTYPE h2 PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">    
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/assets/css/style.css">
 <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">


 <div class="form-group">
    <label for="Mjesto Polaska">Mjesto Polaska</label>
    <input type="mjesto_polaska" class="form-control" id="mjesto_polaska" placeholder="Mjesto Polaska">
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="Mjesto Odredista">Mjesto Odredista</label>
    <input type="mjesto_odredista" class="form-control" id="mjesto_odredista" placeholder="Mjesto Odredista">
  </div>


    <div class="form-group">
  <label for="sel1">Broj slobodnih mjesta:</label>
      <select class="form-control" id="sel1">
        <option>1</option>
        <option>2</option>
        <option>3</option>
        <option>4</option>
      </select>
    </div>

     <div class="form-group">
    <label for="Cijena">Cijena</label>
    <input type="cijena" class="form-control" id="cijena" placeholder="Cijena">
  </div>


    <div class="bootstrap-iso">
    <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <form method="post">
     <div class="form-group ">
      <label class="control-label " for="date">
       Datum Polaska
      </label>
      <div class="input-group">
       <div class="input-group-addon">
        <i class="fa fa-calendar-minus-o">
        </i>
       </div>
       <input class="form-control" id="date" name="date" placeholder="MM/DD/YYYY" type="text"/>
      </div>
     </div>
     <div class="form-group">
      <div>
      </div>
     </div>
    </form>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>


    <div class="bootstrap-iso">
 <div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <form method="post">
     <div class="form-group ">
      <label class="control-label " for="date">
       Datum Povratka
      </label>
      <div class="input-group">
       <div class="input-group-addon">
        <i class="fa fa-calendar-minus-o">
        </i>
       </div>
       <input class="form-control" id="date" name="date" placeholder="MM/DD/YYYY" type="text"/>
      </div>
     </div>
     <div class="form-group">
      <div>
      </div>
     </div>
    </form>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <label for="comment">Opis:</label>
  <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" id="comment"></textarea>
</div>



  <div>
      <button type="Dodaj" class="btn btn-default">Dodaj</button>
  </div>




</head>

</html>
```

Comment: Be more specific on the behavior you're seeing. Does the clicking of the submit button not submit the form? Does the form submit and bring you to the next page? Do you see any errors? Turn error reporting to all if you haven't already.

Comment: @Goose No, nothing. I didn't get the error, I could't open next form, apsolutly nothing happened when I click the button

Answer (score 0):

Your button type must be `submit` when you post data simply into your controller.

Try:

```
 <div>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Dodaj</button>
  </div>
<?php echo form_close();?>
```

Comment: @SalvatoreFerchentoGiuliano so the form does submit when you click the button?

Comment: @SalvatoreFerchentoGiuliano but in the other comment you said "apsolutly nothing happened when I click the button"

Comment: Wrong comment, sorry
I mean, when I press button data couldn't be inserter in database but also I didn't get any error messages